# How can i use selected link value on another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm new with questions and generally with "Stack Overflow", so forgive me if it is not formatted well.

So, I have problem with transferring some informations from one page to another. It is a value of `<a>` tag from an php while loop.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`id`,`o`.`first_name` , `o`.`last_name` , `a`.`name` FROM `owner` AS `o` , `animal` AS `a` WHERE `o`.`id` = `a`.`fk_current_owner` AND `o`.`fk_user` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $pet_id = $row['id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $pet_name = $row['name'];


    echo 'Owner: <strong>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</strong> ';
    echo 'Pet: <strong><a href="viewPet.php" id="'.$pet_id.'">'.$pet_name.'</a></strong><br>';
}
```

So you can assume that this will display names of pets that logged user got.
So I linked their names and I need to get ID of selected name on another page so I can display details of pet on page viewPet.php.

Comment: Take a look at [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Also forget mysql_* and look at PDO or mysqli_* for any database interaction.  mysql_* is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also send the pet id along as a GET parameter with the link.

```
echo '<a href="viewPet.php?id='.$pet_id.'" id="'.$pet_id.'">'.$pet_name.'</a>';
```

On the viewPet.php page you'd access it by $_GET['id']

Answer (score -1):

you can put the link in a cookie:
    setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
that is the code to set the cookie and then to receive the cookie you can do $_COOKIE['name'];

or you can do a session. 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=value;